# Current methods for generic frame buffer?

Tags: assembly, graphics, operating-system, framebuffer

I've been working on a generic frame buffer implementation as part of an OS.  To be clear, I'm saying that there is no Linux kernel or Windows kernel or device drivers available.

My frame buffer is working well (update code below), but I'm looking to improve upon it without going down the route of creating individual drivers for every single manufacturer out there.

> TL;DR

I'm currently using SSE2 and the XMM registers to update the video memory.  I started to venture down the DMA path, but then realized that I'm basing this on what I knew 30 years ago.  DMA feels wrong to use today; what is the next step to better optimize this update process?

```
    const uint32_t h_res = gop->Mode->Info->HorizontalResolution;
    const uint32_t v_res = gop->Mode->Info->VerticalResolution;
    EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_BLT_PIXEL *framebuffer = (void *)(gop->Mode->FrameBufferBase);

    volatile unsigned int ops = (h_res * v_res)/16;

  __asm__ __volatile__(
        "1:"
        "PREFETCHNTA 128(%%rax);"
        "MOVDQA (%%rax), %%xmm0;"
        "MOVDQA 16(%%rax), %%xmm1;"
        "MOVDQA 32(%%rax), %%xmm2;"
        "MOVDQA 48(%%rax), %%xmm3;"
        "MOVDQA 64(%%rax), %%xmm4;"
        "MOVDQA 80(%%rax), %%xmm5;"
        "MOVDQA 96(%%rax), %%xmm6;"
        "MOVDQA 112(%%rax), %%xmm7;"
        "MOVNTDQ %%xmm0, (%%rbx);"
        "MOVNTDQ %%xmm1, 16(%%rbx);"
        "MOVNTDQ %%xmm2, 32(%%rbx);"
        "MOVNTDQ %%xmm3, 48(%%rbx);"
        "MOVNTDQ %%xmm4, 64(%%rbx);"
        "MOVNTDQ %%xmm5, 80(%%rbx);"
        "MOVNTDQ %%xmm6, 96(%%rbx);"
        "MOVNTDQ %%xmm7, 112(%%rbx);"
        "ADDQ $128, %%rax;"
        "ADDQ $128, %%rbx;"
        "DEC %%rcx;"
        "JNZ 1b;"
        : "+a"(canvas), "+b"(framebuffer)
        : "c"(ops)
        : "cc", "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm4", "xmm5", "xmm6", "xmm7", "memory"
    );
```

Comment: I don't think there's something huge performance-wise, except of course not-updating. Still (with outdated knowledge too) some nitpicking: Why `h_res`? Having the buffer always "hres" pixels wide is not that usual in HW, so I wonder whether you may not encounter mode where lines are at offsets different from hres*bpp? And if not, why? I would be worried there's another layer between you and HW, hiding this. Also I'm probably asleep, but why `/16`? `128/16 = 8`, so do you have 8 bytes per pixel, or I'm just confused too much? And `ops` can be calculated once per mode change, kept somewhere.

Comment: About "not-updating" not sure how much you have gfx API under control, but if you have particularly large resolution, and you have full control over gfx updates + only some regions of screen do change, then some dirty-rect optimization may save you lot of data transfers. If this is generic "show the full frame every frame", then this is probably as good as it goes, without using some HW specific ways. The DMA sounds good, but is it even an option on modern x86? Also dedicating one core to this on 4+ core machine will probably resolve any DMA dreams, this will be any way bus-throughput capped?

Comment: @Ped7g Well, I'm dealing with the LFB that EFI provides along with bit-depth.  The EFI boot services is populating that with actual horizontal width.

Comment: @Ped7g I don't have 8 bytes per pixel... I'm moving blocks that are 128 bytes in length through 8 64 bit XMM registers... ;)

Comment: @Ped7g I'm not at the point of dirty-rect updates.  Currently, for performance testing, we're doing full screen animations.  I'm just wondering if there's something that can be done with PCI Bus mastering DMA to take the processor out of the picture with a direct memory to memory move.  It should be faster, but I'd rather get some advice before implementing this using DMA that was designed for an ISA bus, which is what I'm familiar with. :)

Comment: Well, that's completely unknown to me, I know what DMA is, but I have no idea what is current circuitry on modern x86 board, actually the last time I learned some detail about it, I did regret it deeply (I found out the recent laptops have often the "dedicated" graphics card hybrid-connected only directly into the Intel onboard card, technically serving it as coprocessor GPU chip, drawing into Intel's framebuffer, and the Intel is generating the out-signal to LCD, or handling CPU<->Intel_GPU bus connection. The dedicated card is not connected into PC directly at all. Left me in "WTF" state.)

Comment: About 8B pixels.. I must be confused about the math then. `ops = hres*vres/16;` And the asm advances by 128B `ops` many times. So for 800x600 that's 800*600/16*128 = 3840000 bytes, that's 8 per pixel? Where went I wrong? Also 8 64b XMMs = 512b = 64B, so it looks like you copy interleaved 8B copy / 8B missed ... I'm sorry if I'm not seeing something obvious (will take some more coffein soon ;)) But the asm looks to me like you load 128 bit XMM regs with +16B offsets, moving 128B. If the mode is 32bpp, then this looks like moving 2x more pixels.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll double check the math on that.. I might have the ability to save some time there. :)

Comment: @Ped7g indeed, I need to look over my math... ;)  Simply doing that has accelerated things by several times. ;)  Thanks

Comment: Using DMA would require device specific code, as every video card has its own hardware interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About wrong number of bytes copied (from comments).

I would suggest to write the code in block-size agnostic way:

```
const uint32_t h_res = gop->Mode->Info->HorizontalResolution;
const uint32_t v_res = gop->Mode->Info->VerticalResolution;
EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_BLT_PIXEL *framebuffer = (void *)(gop->Mode->FrameBufferBase);
EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_BLT_PIXEL *end_of_frame = framebuffer + (h_res * v_res);
// "ops" removed
```

or if you don't want to calculate it on your own, there's this `FrameBufferSize` provided too:

```
UINT8* end_of_frame = ((UINT8*)framebuffer) + gop->Mode->FrameBufferSize;
```

... and in asm, load `rcx` with `end_of_frame` instead and ...

```
    ...
    "ADDQ $128, %%rbx;"
    "ADDQ $128, %%rax;"
    "CMP %%rcx, %%rbx;"
    "JB 1b;"
    ...
```

(I'm not used to do inline and gas syntax, so double check before using)

With this you can later change the block code any way you wish (if you will experiment further), the terminating compare doesn't depend on block size any more. It will actually survive even if total frame length is not divisible by block size, so it will terminate after the last block is written (over the boundary of the frame).

Comment: That was sort of unexpectedly cheap gain ... :) I didn't even dream I will be of such huge help (speaking by percentage of performance) while actually not providing any info you were looking for. ;)

Comment: Well, that's what happens when you write code at 3am and do all of the math in your head. :)

Comment: You're not calculating the size of the frame buffer correctly in your first example. I'ts actually `VerticalResolution * PixelsPerScanLine * PixelElementSize` where `PixelElementSize` is calculated as shown in the example code showing the intended field usage of EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_MODE_INFORMATION in the UEFI spec. There's no guarantee that this number is an even multiple of 128, and @DavidHoelzer 's source buffer would need to use the same pitch as the LFB.

Comment: Thanks @RossRidge  When the other math error was pointed out, I actually found this and corrected it.

Comment: @RossRidge: I was in doubt about `h_res` usage too, in my very first comment. I just didn't check the specs myself. Also my example in first variant works only for 32bpp modes. The second variant with `FrameBufferSize` should work. If the pitch is considerable, he would probably save even some time by skipping the off-screen part of lines (and usually the pitch is done to fix alignment of line, so then it's win-win for start of next line).